# sending input in java as if a button was pressed

Tags: java, input, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to make a program that if you would press a button, it would send a message to the computer as if a button on the keyboard was pressed, kinda like the on screen keyboard the pc has, or something like that. How can i tell the program to send a "message" as such? do i need to use scanner?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java Robot class for this purpose.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html
for example :

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```